# MacOS Big Sur - Python ctypes find_library does not find libraries (ssl, CoreFoundation, etc

Tags: python, macos, ctypes

MacOS Big Sur is out in Dev Beta and I am running it to test out a few things. One of the things I've noticed is that in Python ctypes, `find_library()` no longer finds the libraries.

An example would be

```py
from ctypes.util import find_library

find_library("ssl")
```

This should find the `ssl` file similar to the output like

```
>>> find_library("ssl")
'libssl.so.1.1'
```

However, with Big Sur, it finds nothing. I noticed their are some Dynamic Linker changes. That might contribute to this behavior.

Has anyone else encountered this? I am looking for the new method for finding libraries across the Big Sur system.

I believe it is the same as iOS in that it's using `/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64` for shared cache. But I am not familiar enough to know how to open that file for accessing things like CoreFoundations, ssl, etc. Still looking into it.

Comment: What version of Python have Apple shipped with macOS Big Sur? Some of the changes could just be Python 2/3 changes...

Comment: @peterjc Python 2.7.16, Python 3.8.2

Comment: This same issue seems to affect versions of JNA for Java with the message `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'CoreFoundation': Native library (darwin/libCoreFoundation.dylib) not found in resource path`

Comment: @tresf yes, it will affect basically everything not using static paths. If you use a static path, it should worth though.

Comment: @Terminal thanks, but from what I've found, starting with Big Sur, there's no static path to these any longer.    Bug report with more details: https://github.com/nyholku/purejavahidapi/issues/75

Comment: Big Sur "should" do the mapping for you. They are still a "static" path in the sense that Apple still has a path associated with that file in memory. `dlopen() the path, which will correctly check for the library in the cache` meaning for instance that if you pass a path (which is mapped in memory) then it will open the cached library. See this image for what I mean https://imgur.com/R0THV1i  that is because the path `/usr/lib/libssl.44.dylib` is in memory but Apple has mapped it to that path

Answer (score 6):

This issue is due to python using `stat()` to check for dylibs on disk before it dlopen's them.  This behaviour stopped working in macOS Big Sur due to dylibs being removed from disk when they are included in the dyld shared cache.

The python included in macOS has a fix for this.

```
/usr/bin/python3
from ctypes.util import find_library
>>> find_library("ssl")
'libssl.so.1.1'
```

Additionally, here is a link to a pull request for open source python for the same fix there.  https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/21241

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using static paths for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally consider that as of Python 3.9.0, 3.8.6, 3.7.9
MacOS 11 or Apple Silicon aren't supported. Track the progress here:
https://bugs.python.org/issue41100